# How to change vlc interface font

Tags: vlc

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWcmR.png)

I recently installed vlc on antergos and the font is so ugly, any way to change it?

Comment: You could try under tools->preferences->interfaces, or changing the theme in your OS.  But Antergos is not Ubuntu.

Comment: are there any ask arch?

Comment: There's unix&linux, and superuser

Comment: You could just change the question to "on Ubuntu"!

Answer (score 0):

You can download and use skins from official site (or create your own):

*Tools -> Interface -> Look and feel*

By the way - try to change *Force window style* ( *breeze* looks better)

As I know, VLC allows only change subtitle fonts.